# Pass input element into a function to format user entered string to a "date"

Tags: javascript, html

I have spent a few hours now trying to figure out how to pass an input element into a formatting function I found on this site. So sorry if I am duplicating.

Basically I have an input on the form where the user will either type a string in either a, DD-MM-YY(YY), or MM-DD-YY(YY) format and I am trying to get a function to fire at onchange making it format to DD Month, YYYY. I don't actually need it to be a date, it can remain a string (I just noticed everyone talks about running strings into Date() ). I would only like to use HTML and Javascript if possible.

I am not worried about getting the format down because I can write the code that changes the way it appears, I just cannot seem to get the actual dateOfManufacture.value to change at all. I don't really grasp passing arguments into a function enough to make this happen currently.

```
<input type="text" id="dateOfManufacture">

<!-- Date function found on this site -->
function toDate(dateStr) {
    var parts = dateStr.split("-");
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}
```

Wouldn't I want to do something like?

```
<input type="text" id="dateOfManufacture" onchange="toDate(this)">
```

This doesn't work, so how do I set the passed inputs.value as the returned date? 
By passing "this" at onchange that should put the input into the function as dateStr correct? Then it should get delimited by the dateStr.split("-"), correct? Is the return portion incorrect and it should be

```
dateStr.value = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
```

Meaning that after the delimiting of the input.value, the input.value is assigned the value of the new Date object created from the delimited input.value?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: did you try with try with onkeypress?

Comment: `this` in inline event handler declaration (like onchange="...") refers to the HTMLElement instance so the `dateStr ` argument in this case is an object. You can access the value via `dateStr.value` property.

Comment: You can also use [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to create a Date object from various date format strings.

Comment: @Marekful - So you are saying that I have to pass this.value at the onchange event function call since "this" just passes the entire object? The next thing is I tried to return and then assign the dateStr.value to the newDate and it still does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `Date.parse( dateStr.value )`

Comment: I got the passing to work, Thanks!